# How to change Windows Dev Center language?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-store

I'm from Poland, but I'm using English version of both Windows all my browsers. I have also set English as my default or the only language in all these browsers.

Both [Windows Dev Center](https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/en-us/Home/Index) and [Windows Phone Dev Center](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/dashboard) appears in English in all of these browsers... except for Internet Explorer, where first (Windows Dev Center) is in Polish.

Anyone knows, what is used to determine user language? And if there is any way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use default link to access Windows Dev Center dashboard:

```
https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/
```

You will be most likely redirected to your language version, for example (in my case -- Polish):

```
https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/pl-pl/Home/Index
```

You can simply change this to English dashboard:

```
https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/en-us/Home/Index
```

and start using above link, instead of "default" to access Windows Dev Center dashboard each time. Simply update all your bookmarks and links to this one and enjoy dashboard in English.

<sup>*What causes English Internet Explorer on English Windows to detect Polish language in my case and redirect me to Polish version of Windows Dev Center, and why this "trick" works only in case of Windows Dev Center, but not in case of Windows Phone Dev Center -- remains mystery for me.*</sup>